# How to implement facebook messenger chat in my personal react website?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, chat, messenger

I tried to implement the Facebook messenger customer chat plugin to my react project but somehow it's not showing on my website. I tried to use the react-messenger-customer-chat module to use this feature but in the console, there was an error named tracking prevention. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check for these potential issues:

1. Have you provided correct pageId and appId?
2. Is the page public?
3. Have you included your domain in whitelisted domains in your page settings?
4. Is the domain https? (http is not supported).